# How to load the fixtures from an Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I've extracted my models into a mountable engine and now I want the host-app (the app including that mountable engine) to use the fixtures from that engine.

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Add fixtures from the mounted engine "blorgh"
  fixture_path = Blorgh::Engine.root.join("test", "fixtures")
  fixtures :all
end
```

Debugging learns that fixture_path is correctly set, to something like `/home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@x/bundler/gems/blorgh-07520673953b/test/fixtures/`. This is the correct path with the correct fixtures.

But, somehow the fixtures appear not to get loaded. The database remains empty. And the helpers are not available. E.g. a fixture `contacts.yml` normally leads to the helper `contacts(:harry)`. This helper is not set, because the fixtures were not loaded.

The engine is not namespaced, but for the sake of completeness, `blorgh_contacts(:harry)` is not defined either.

How can I use the fixtures from an engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, which I feel is more concise.

```
self.fixture_path = Blorgh::Engine.root.join("test", "fixtures")
```

Comment: Afaik, the `File.join()` already returns a string, so `to_s` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
self.fixture_path = Rails.root.parent + "./fixtures/ads"
```

Comment: Ahh, off course: it is a class-method. I am merely setting a variable.